# How to send AT commands in Keil

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32, uart, at-command

I am using HC-05 bluetooth module and STM32F407. I am trying to change the name of the bluetooth module. I can enter AT Command Mode, but i can't send any AT Commands to module. I tried something in `main`. But it didn't work

I see

```
huart->Instance->DR = (*pData++ & (uint8_t)0xFF);
```

in my Transmit function. Also, i see ascii values of elements in `DR`

Here is my try.

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "string.h"

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void);

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  char* data = "AT+NAME=charles \n\r";
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t *)data, strlen(data), 2000);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */
  while (1)
  {
  }
}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart3.Instance = USART3;
  huart3.Init.BaudRate = 38400;
  huart3.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart3.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart3.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart3.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart3.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart3.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}


static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbxqx.png
```

Comment: Why are you going through all the trouble of creating this arbitrary-length character buffer, using `sprintf` to print to it(??) and then sending that? This is really bizarre.

Comment: Would you like to tell us more about what does not work? It is not clear from your question. What do you expect? And what do you get?

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation of supported AT commands for this device? If so please provide it. Also according to this documentation, https://www.developershome.com/sms/atCommandsIntro2.asp I'm not sure if your `AT` command is properly formatted. Should it be `char* data = "AT+NAME=\"charles\"\r";` ?

Comment: If you use char* data = "AT+NAME?"\r";` do you get a response back with the current name of the device? I suggest you try using queries to check that you get a response back to double check that the connection to the device is working properly.

Comment: And what is the infinite loop after the `HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t *)data, strlen(data), 2000);`? Is there a call back or interrupt routine that is handling the UART and its response?

Comment: Yes my command is properly formatted. I checked datasheet. No i cannot get a response. There is no any interrupt or callback.

Comment: @HernanCrespo I see at least something wrong: terminator char for AT commands is '\r' only, not '\n\r'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a character buffer:

```
static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void)
{
   char* data = "AT+NAME=charles \n\r";
   HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t *)data, strlen(data), 2000);
}
```

That's all you need. You called `sprintf` as if it was `strcpy` and the first argument is an uninitialized character buffer.

Comment: This is clearly better code and saves RAM. But it does exactly the same to the module and I'm afraid that it does *not* solve the questioners problem.

Comment: I think `data` (in the OP code) will be initialized to 0 before jumping to the main (CRT). So I agree with @thebusybee

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean What will changed if it is not initialized? The net effect is still the same.

Comment: I fully agree, I was just reacting to the remark about uninitialised array. Anyway we don't even know what the problem is... :)

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific than "didn't work". Does the `HAL_UART_Transmit()` function return a diagnostic value?

Answer (score 0):

as tadman said, you don't need this:

```c
uint8_t data[50];
```

But this is not a `uninitialized character buffer` as tadman said.